# How to write a function in the H2 database without using Java

Tags: sql, h2

This question is reference to question ["How to create stored procedure using H2 database?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098905/how-to-create-stored-procedure-using-h2-database) (continuation of the same question).

Is there a way to write a function in H2 without using Java code? My requirement is to translate the functions written in SQL to H2 without using Java code. I found lot of examples in different portals doing the same using Java code. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Arun

Comment: I don't think this is possible in H2. You might want to look at HSQLDB which supports procedures in its own SQL dialect and does not require Java for that. Btw: what do you mean with "*written in SQL*"? Which DBMS is you source? (SQL is **only** a *query* language it is **not** a DBMS product).

Comment: If you look [here](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions) at the h2 Documentation it states "In addition to the [built-in functions](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html), this database supports user-defined Java functions". i.e. you create your procedures as java code then create aliases for them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Iam using **MsSqlDatabase** and the function is written for MsSqlDB. Then the only wayout to write procedures in H2 is through Java Code..?

Comment: @JavaDevil : Thank you. I read it but believed that there will be a tweak for it. :( .

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Currently, H2 does only support functions written in Java or a related language (for example Groovy or Scala). [PL/SQL (Oracle)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL) and [T-SQL (MS SQL Server, Sybase)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL) are not supported.

Comment: Does H2 still doesn't support Stored Procedure so our query doesn't have to be recompiled every time and rest of the features of SP?

Comment: @AbdulJabbarWebBestow sorry I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 5):

If your primary goal is to run SQL (or SQLesque) statements within your H2 Java user-defined functions, [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) could be an option as a ["PL/Java" implementation](http://blog.jooq.org/2013/04/27/jooq-as-a-pljava-language/). Of course, this would still be a Java solution.

An example of such a function can be seen in this blog post:

http://blog.jooq.org/2011/11/04/use-jooq-inside-your-h2-database

```java
public class Functions {
    public static int countBooks(Connection connection, Integer authorId) 
    throws SQLException {
        // Translate your T-SQL statements to jOOQ statements
        return DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.H2)
                  .selectCount()
                  .from(BOOK)
                  .where(BOOK.AUTHOR_ID.eq(authorId))
                  .fetchOne(0, int.class);
    }
}
```

Declare the above method as an ALIAS to H2

```sql
CREATE ALIAS countBooks 
   FOR "org.example.Functions.countBooks";
```

Use the function in SQL

```sql
SELECT author.last_name, countBooks(author.id) 
FROM author
```

A similar approach can be taken with H2's own SQL abstraction [JaQu](http://www.h2database.com/html/jaqu.html), of course. Using JaQu wouldn't add any additional dependency, I think.

Comment: Just what I was looking for!