# Is there any inmemory database which supports stored procedure?

Tags: java, stored-procedures, spring-boot, in-memory-database

I have spring boot application which is has spring ws and backend as Stored procedure, I am trying to write integration tests for this and looking for inmemmory database which supports stored procedure?

i tried with h2 database but it looks for java functions to work on stored procedure. i sthere any direct mechanism where I can put my stored procedure with minimal effort?

Comment: May be the below link will help you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293598/how-to-write-a-function-in-the-h2-database-without-using-java/17295917#17295917

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, there is no ready made solution. i needed this for integration testing but solution provide by h2 database required me to rewrite the stored procedure in java classes. http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions

Considering the pain to write integration test and amount of effort, I decided to go against it. Hope it may help to some else.