# How to create STUFF function in H2 in memory database?

Tags: java, h2db

How to create STUFF function in H2 in memory database? This is required to write  Junit for a DAO function which uses query having "STUFF" function to query MS SQL database.

I tried extending H2Dialect but not sure how to register this function in H2.

Kindly suggest

Comment: It seems that Transact-SQL functions are not supported by H2 ([How to write a function in the H2 database without using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293598/how-to-write-a-function-in-the-h2-database-without-using-java)).

Comment: @MickMnemonic:- Yes it seems to be like that.